# Drawing an Image and updating it if Window is resized

Tags: java, swing, file-io, bufferedimage

I am drawing an Image in Java and I want to update the Image to the size of the window if it got resized. But since I am a beginner I dont know at all what I should do.

```
public class ImageCanvas extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel panel; 
    JLabel label; 
    ImageIcon icon; 
    BufferedImage image; 

    public ImageCanvas() throws IOException{
        draw();
        icon = new ImageIcon(image); 
        label = new JLabel(icon); 
        panel = new JPanel(); 
        panel.add(label); 
        getContentPane().add(panel); 
        setSize(image.getWidth()+10, image.getHeight()); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true); 
        File f = new File("c:\\img.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);
    }

    private void draw() {
        int width = 640, height = 480; 
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster(); 
        ColorModel model = image.getColorModel(); 

        Color c1 = Color.BLACK; 
        int argb1 = c1.getRGB(); 
        Object data1 = model.getDataElements(argb1, null); 

        Color c2 = Color.RED; 
        int argb2 = c2.getRGB(); 
        Object data2 = model.getDataElements(argb2, null); 
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) { 
                    raster.setDataElements(i, j, data1); 
                    if(i==j){
                        raster.setDataElements(i, j, data2);
                    }
                } 
            }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        new ImageCanvas(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The `private void draw() {` method should be `@Override public void paint(Graphics g) {` instead.  But that should really be `paintComponent(Graphics)` in a `JPanel` that returns a preferred size & maximum size based on the original size of the image, but draws a [scaled image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getScaleInstance%28double,%20double%29) otherwise. 2) `setSize(image.getWidth()+10, image.getHeight());` change to `pack();`. 3) `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` change to `setLocationByPlatform(true); // nice..` ;)

Answer (score 0):

A JLabel always paints the icon as its actual size. You would need to recreate the image every time the label is resized.

An easier approach is to do dynamic painting which will resize the image as required. [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) can do this for you.